# How do you automatically copy a formula across a row if the header contains text?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have a Google Sheet that transposes a list of items as the headers of the sheet. This list changes frequently +/- which means that the number of column headers (row 2) change frequently. On the first row (under the header) I have a formula that populates the column contents based on the header name. How do I get my formula to only copy to ALL the columns that have a header name and not to the ones that are empty.

Note the empty columns need to be there.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(2:2="",,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:3500<>"", 1, 0)), 
 ROW(3:3500)^0))&" Results"))
```

Comment: you may add a filter so that formulas end at desired column {  =filter(  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(2:2="",,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:3500<>"", 1, 0)), ROW(3:3500)^0))&" Results"))  ,column(2:2)<=arrayformula(LARGE(if(len(A3:CZ3),column(A3:CZ3),0),1)))  }

Comment: How can you transpose the following formula across all of row 3 of the "Appends" tab if the cell contents of row 2 has text? =if(Inputs!$B$3="","enter a keyword in cell A2 of Inputs",unique(GOOGLE_SUGGEST(Inputs!$B$3,Inputs!$E$3,Inputs!$E$4)))

Comment: Btw, the google function is a apps script function that does a url fetch of the keyword field (Inputs!B3 contents) and modifier (row 2 contents).

Comment: this may need to be solved with a script because nor unique nor GOOGLE_SUGGEST are supported by arrayformula